# How to define dynamic selector with Ruby/Appium and new UiSelector()

Tags: ruby, automation, cucumber, appium

1. I have a gherkin step
   `And I switch to "About" tab`
2. Step is created

```
    And (/^I switch to "([^"]*)" tab$/) do |tabName|
      @screens.main.switch_to_tab(tabName)
    end
```

3. Method to click on that selector is created

```
class Main
  
  def tab_button
    @tab_button = Elements.new(:uiautomator,`new UiSelector().resourceId(tab-button-#{@tab})`)
  end

  def switch_to_tab(tabName) 
    @tab = tabName.downcase  
    tab_button 
    @tab_button.click
  end

end
```

```
And console throws error
 Could not parse selector expression `new UiSelector().resourceId(tab-button-about)`: `UiSelector` doesn't have suitable method `resourceId` with arguments ¡tab-button-about¿: Could not parse selector expression `new UiSelector().resourceId(tab-button-about)`: tab-button-about is not a string; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors£invalid-selector-exception (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError)
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved
Used double quotes

```
@tab_button = Elements.new(:uiautomator, "new UiSelector().resourceId(\"tab-button-#{@tab}\")")
```